# Как сделать, чтобы после отправки формы. В письме было видно название Товара, который заказали?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

как сделать, чтобы видно было название товара в письме который заказал человек.
Пример письма с почты: Телефон: +79097526445 Имя: Артем Почта: Вопрос: Товар: Источник:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { // вся мaгия пoсле зaгрузки стрaницы
  $('.btn-bay').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline'
  });
  $(".product").val($(this).data('name'));
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  //E-mail Ajax Send
  $("form").submit(function() { //Change
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "send.php", //Change
      data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
      swal({
        title: "Отлично!",
        text: "Ваше сообщение отправлено",
        icon: "success",
        button: "Хорошо",
      });
      setTimeout(function() {
        $.magnificPopup.close();
      }, 1000);

    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="submit btn-bay" href="#form" data-name="Белый">Заказать</a>


<div class="hidden">
  <form action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call(this)" method="post" id="form">
    <span id="modal_close"><img src="img/25/close.svg"></span>
    <!-- Кнoпкa зaкрыть -->
    <div class="callback-form__title">Отличный выбор!</div>
    <div class="inputs">
      <div class="input">
        <label class="header">Введите имя *</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="callback-form__field" placeholder="Иван Иванов">
      </div>
      <div class="input">
        <label class="header">Введите телефон *</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="callback-form__field" placeholder="+7 (945) 777-00-00" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="product" class="product">
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="<?=@$_GET['utm_source']?>">
    <button type="submit" class="callback-form__btn btn">Заказать </button>
    <p class="politic">Заполняя форму, вы соглашаетесь с<br><a href="teddy-kmv.ru/politika.php">Политикой Конфиденциальности</a></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
 $(".product").val($(this).data('name'));
```

на

```
$(".product").val($('.btn-bay').attr('data-name'));
```

и должно работать. Сейчас правда ошибка magnificPopup ибо функция вроде в плагине который не прикрепили

Comment: Да работает спасибо большое. Только пишет вместо название товара например "Красный мишка". Пишет "Заказали звонок". У меня просто класс .btn-bay ко всем формам добавлен

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как добавить несколько классов в один скрипт. Это вот так например: $(document).ready(function() { // вся мaгия пoсле зaгрузки стрaницы
  $('.btn-bay', '.btn-callback').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline'
  });
  $(".product").val($('.btn-bay', '.btn-callback').attr('data-name'));
});

Comment: $('.submit.btn-bay') - объект содержит оба класса $('.submit, .btn-bay')  объекты с классами submit и объекты с классами btn-bay

Comment: <a href="#callform" class="btn-callback" data-name="Заказали звонок">Заказать звонок</a> в письме он вот этот data-name показывает. Т.е. "Заказали звонок". А мне нужно <a class="submit btn-bay" href="#form" data-name="Белый">Заказать</a>

Comment: @Артем ну вешать на нужную кнопку уникальный id/class, обращаться через уникальный родительский id/тэг/class - разные есть варианты. Надо смотреть весь код.

Comment: Все я решил вопрос. Просто поменял каждой форме class="product". Благодарю Вас за помощь. Хорошего дня)